# YAML pipeline that will build the solution, publish it, and archive the results

Tags: c#, yaml, devops, pipeline

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2022 with several projects (some of them are class libraries, some are function apps, and some are Xunit test projects), and they have a similar path (only the last prefix is different), for example `Management.Projects`, `Management.Projects.Tests`, and `Management.Projects.Library`. I am a new to YAML pipelines and I have a problem writing a YAML pipeline that should build all the projects in a solution, publish them in one folder, and archive the result as a .zip.

Currently I am trying to achive this with this taks:

```
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          inputs:
            command: 'build'
            projects: '**\*.sln'

        - task: ExtractFiles@1
          inputs:
            archiveFilePatterns: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
            destinationFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)'
            cleanDestinationFolder: true
            overwriteExistingFiles: false

        - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
          inputs:
            PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)'
            ArtifactName: 'drop'
            publishLocation: 'Container'
            
        - task: ArchiveFiles@2
          inputs:
            rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
            archiveType: zip
            includeRootFolder: true
            archiveFile: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip"
```

But it's throw exceptions such as `##[error]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.` or even when everything is successful, the .zip file is empty. Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to change followig down.

```
before:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

after:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId)'
```

If you continue to face issues, consider adding ls or dir commands in your pipeline to print out the contents of relevant directories to debug where files are located and whether they match the expected paths.